# Expo Background Location Close when app minimize or device blocked

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am using React Native (0.70.5) and Expo (47.0.9).

I'm using location in the background to follow the user's movement during their workday, but I'm having a problem that when I lock the cell phone or minimize the application, the location stops working.

Tested both in production, with generated apk, and via Expo. None of the formats work.

```
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import * as BackgroundFetch from 'expo-background-fetch'
...
const TASK_NAME = "background-location-task";

const myComponent = () => {
 useEffect(() => {
    const start = async () => {
      await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(TASK_NAME, {
        minimumInterval: 25,
        stopOnTerminate: false,
        startOnBoot: true,
      });
      // await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(TASK_NAME, {
      //   accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
      //   distanceInterval: 0,
      //   timeInterval: 25000,
      // });
    }
    start()
  }, []);
...
}

TaskManager.defineTask(TASK_NAME, async ({ data: { locations }, error }) => {
  console.log("I am here", new Date())
})
```

If you can see my useeffect, i already tried with BackgroundFetch and Location.

I already set my app.json android.permission with access_background_location and in android folder too!

Someone can help me ?

If you can see my useeffect, i already tried with BackgroundFetch and Location.

I need to track background location